# how to set property using jasmine createSpyObj method in angular

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine, angular-test

In my angular service I have a property `myPropertyOne: Observable<string>` and I want to mock the property using jasmine.createSpyObj method. so, I tried spying like below

```
  const myServiceSpy: jasmine.SpyObj<myService> = jasmine.createSpyObj('myService', ['myMethodOne'], ['myPropertyOne'])
```

I want to set value for my spied property 'myPropertyOne'. Also, this value should be changed for different test spec against to be tested. Appreciate if someone can suggest on this.

*Note: I tried checking other threads and not getting clear idea on how to set and get property value using createSpyObj.*

Comment: You only need to supply the *methods* to `createSpyObj`, you can set properties with just `myServiceSpy.myPropertyOne = ...`.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I accept this also works! Instead of setting property each time in each spec, tried using replay subject. many thanks.

Answer (score 4):

@Viswa was on the right path, but actually the correct syntax is:

```js
const mySubject: ReplaySubject<string> = new ReplaySubject<string>(1)
const myServiceSpy: jasmine.SpyObj<myService> = jasmine.createSpyObj(
  'myService', 
  ['myMethodOne'], 
  {'myPropertyOne': mySubject }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

At last, I tried like below and it worked

```
  const mySubject: ReplaySubject<string> = new ReplaySubject<string>(1)

  const myServiceSpy: jasmine.SpyObj<myService> = jasmine.createSpyObj('myService', ['myMethodOne'], ['myPropertyOne': {mySubject}])
```

with this, in my test spec, I set string in my subject like below.

```
describe('my component', () => {
    it('some test check', () => {
        mySubject.next('some value')
        fixture.detectChanges()
        // some assertion
    })
})
```

Comment: Visual code doesnt even allow me to do this ['myPropertyOne': {mySubject}].  Incorrect syntax error is what im getting.